# inside API scrollViewDidScroll , shows sender correct but sender.contentSize is showing null while calculating page number

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview, scrollview

I want to find page number in scroll view consisting of uiimage view.

Inside the method, `- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)sender`

on logging it shows sender value properly  i.e everything about scroller correct,

but for calculation when i use `sender.contentOffSet.x` then it shows null

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try using following method of UIScrollViewProtocol

`- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView`

Default value if contentSize is zero....see following details from apple documentation.

> contentOffset
> The point at which the origin of the content view is offset from the origin of the scroll view.
>
> Discussion
> The default value is CGPointZero.

> contentSize
>
> The size of the content view.
>
> Discussion
> The unit of size is points. The default size is CGSizeZero.
>
> Related Sample Code
> QuartzDemo

Comment: Default value of contentOffset is zero....so I think you will not be able to access it if you do not provide value in contentSize.

Comment: Following worked for me in code after providing contentSize ......floor((scrollView.contentOffset.x - pageWidth / 2))

Comment: I have tried with setting contentOffSet, but now it comes to home screen without logging any exception..what does it means??

Comment: setting contentOffset may not work when contentSize is not defined. Still to try running your application without attaching from debugger and when it crashes check device log in Window->Organizer->(select device)->See log section to find exception details.